# Building a calculator, unable to add numbers to the display panel

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, calculator

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn a beginners project by building a calculator. I have just started the project.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        display.text = display.text! + digit
    }

}
```

[image]

However, when I run the project, if I press any number to the left, it is suppose to add this particular number to the display to the top right hand corner. However, what happen instead is that the project will freeze and XCode's debugger will pop up and display something like this:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally added a break point at line number 16 (that blue arrow is a break point). Remove it by dragging it out. It has nothing to do with swift, Break points are useful when you are debugging.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much!! I'm very new to Swift. I thought something is wrong with my code and have spend nearly two hours on this problem already. you saved me!! Really appreciate your help!!

Comment: God bless you bro :)